# Iterated integrals in general ( and double integral )

Tags: integration

> $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb R,$ defined by $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}1,\quad \ \ y\in\mathbb R\text{\\}\mathbb Q\\2x,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$.

$1.1$: $\int_0^1f(x,y)dx$ exists for every $y\in[0,1]$ and is equal to $1$.

$1.2$: The iterated integral $\int_0^1(\int_0^1f(x,y)dx)dy$ exists and is $1$.

$1.3$: The double integral $\int_If(x,y)d(x,y)$ does not exist.

I am struggling with solving iterated integrals in general and with this one I don't even know where to start since the values kind of jump from 1 to 2x constantly.

Edit: Got an idea for 1.1.: I made two cases, one for an irrational y and one for the rest. 
Giving me $\int_0^11dx$ which is 1 and $\int_0^12xdx$ which also is 1.

Could someone give me a short explanation about them and some hints on how to approach these exercises?

Comment: For 1.1, $y$ is fixed for the integration, so either $f(x,y) = 1$ for all $x$ of $f(x,y) = 2x$ for all $x$. There is no jumping around. At least, I'm not jumping around.

Comment: Do you have to take Riemann or Lebesgue integrals?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability): it works quickly for 1.1 and 1.2. For 1.3 you might want to note that there is a version of this criterion for functions of several values too (which essentially says the same: a bounded function is Riemann-integrable $\iff$ it is continuous almost everywhere). Therefore, in fact, your problem is less one on integration and more one on continuity.

Answer (score 0):

First notes:

(1) have you solved correctly.

For (2) you can plug in your solution $\int_0^1f(x,y)dx=1$ into the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy$ to get $\int_0^11dy$ which you can solve easily...

For (3) have a look at [Is Dirichlet function Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437711/is-dirichlet-function-riemann-integrable) and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1167830/32951 (I guess you have to consider the Riemann not the Lebesgue integral)

Comment: On (3): So basically, because the irrational and rational numbers are too "dense" on each interval $[a,b]$ and the supremum therefore is 1 and the infimum is 0 and they are therefore not equal, it is not Rimann integrable?

Comment: @Rab: Yes. Note, that in your case you will end up with $\int_I 2x dxdy$ as a lower bound, not zero...

Comment: How come it's $\int_I2xdxdy$ and not 2x then? Isn't the integral 1 on $I$?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake... I meant $\int_I min(2x,1)dxdy$...

Comment: Then the upper bound also isn't 1 but $\int_Imax(2x,1)dxdy$?

Comment: You are right! ;-)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help.