# Why this function is not Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Why this function is not Riemann integrable on [0, 1] ? \begin{equation}
f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
x & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We can calculate the upper integral and lower integral, $\overline{\int}f\left(x\right)dx=0.5$, $\underline{\int}f\left(x\right)dx=0$, therefore, the Riemann's criterion does not hold. So the function is not Riemann inegrable.

But if you use the Lebesgue theorem, bounded function on [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities of $f\left(x\right)$ has measure zero.

We know that (1) every finite set has measure zero, and (2) every countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero.

The rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and the rational numbers $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence, the set of discontinuities of $f\left(x\right)$ on [0, 1] has measure zero. Therefore $f\left(x\right)$ is Riemann integrable.

What are the mistakes here? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $(0,1]$

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ isn't countable!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $f$ defined by $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)=0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, is not integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098636/prove-that-f-defined-by-fx-1-if-x-in-mathbbq-fx-0-if-x-in-ma)

Answer (score 1):

well, your discontinuities are a lot more than $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ they are in fact all of $[0,1]$, since it is the boundary that matters. or show me one point apart from $0$ where your function is continuous!

Comment: The function is continuous at $x=0$

Comment: Fair point! I apologize