# $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin (\frac{1}{\cos (x)})$ convergence verification

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I wish to check if the integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin (\frac{1}{\cos (x)})$$

is converging.

Here is what I did:

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin (\frac{1}{\cos (x)})\lt \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin (\frac{1}{1})=\sin (1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ so the integral converge.

Is this true?

Comment: But $\sin(x) \le 1$, so $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(1/\cos(x))dx \le \int_0^{\pi/2} dx$ ...

Comment: @johannesvalks thank you

Comment: And please, when you compare the function to something else, take absolute value !

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS good comment. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea might be correct, but what you wrote certainly is not, since $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)<\sin (1)$$ is not true.

It is not true for example for $$x=\arccos\frac{2}{\pi}$$ in which case $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)=\sin(\frac\pi2)=1>\sin(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

As

$$-1 \le \sin(x) \le +1$$

we get

$$-\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \le \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right) dx \le \int_0^{\pi/2} dx$$

so

$$-\frac{\pi}2 \le \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right) dx \le \frac{\pi}2$$

Comment: thank you. nice answer

Comment: Not nice answer, no. $\int_0^X \sin(t) dt = 1-\cos(X)$, so $0\le \int_0^X \sin(t) dt \le 2$, but that doesn't mean $\int_0^{+\infty} \sin(t)dt$ is convergent ! For example, what sense do you give to $\int_0^1 \chi(t)dt$, where $\chi(t)=1$ if $t\in\mathbb Q$, else $0$ ?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, $-X \le \int_0^X \sin(f(x)) dx \le X$, for continues $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, given your definition of $\chi(t)$, we get $0 \le \int_0^1 \chi(t) dt \le 1$...

Comment: @johannesvalks : does this mean $\chi$ is integrable ??? mathematicians had to find a VERY GOOD integral to give a sense to $\int_0^1\chi$ ! According to Riemann, this integrale DOESN'T exist !

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, Riemann cannot - but Lebesque can ;)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755576/the-lebesgue-integral-and-the-dirichlet-function

Comment: @johannesvalks : I know all this. I just wanted to mention that saying the function is bounded is not enough to declare it integrable. Hence the "Not nice answer" comment. Now if you accept Lebesgue as your primary tool, everything becomes much cooler. But there is a price to pay !