# Continuity of the function $\varphi (x) = 1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi (x) = -1$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am supposed to prove the continuity of function: 
$$\varphi (x) = \left\{\begin{align}
1  &, \quad x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 
-1 &, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{align}\right.$$
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Arthur I tried to draw it, but it did not help me

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I supposed you used the usual metric on  $\mathbb{R}$ ?  And in what sense you should study its continuity ?  I mean can you deal with open sets?

Comment: HINT: The function is discontinuous everywhere. To prove this, it suffices to show for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x'\in(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ and $\varphi(x)\neq\varphi(x')$.

Comment: @Nizar yes, I can. There is also a question connected with it, if it is Riemann and Newton integrable

Comment: @79037662 yes, I edited it

Comment: What difficulties do you have in following the *definition* of continuity?

Comment: If you actually want to ask the (Riemann) integrability of this function: see [Is Dirichlet function Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437711/9464)

Comment: @MartinN.：Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "take as $t$"?

Comment: Definition of contnuity as it is write below is :∀ε>0∃δ>0∀t∈R(|t−x|<δ⟹|φ(t)−φ(x)|<ε and I did not know what to take as t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the "definition" of continuity (using $\varepsilon-\delta$) to prove that $\varphi$ is discontinuous; I will also use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense (and hence $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$).

The definition tells you that $\varphi$ is continuous at a point $x\in\mathbb R$ if and only if

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0\;\forall t\in\mathbb R(|t-x|<\delta\;\Longrightarrow\;|\varphi(t)-\varphi(x)|<\varepsilon);$$

thus, $\varphi$ is discontinuous at a point $x\in\mathbb R$ if and only if

$$\exists\varepsilon>0\;\forall\delta>0\;\exists t\in\mathbb R(|t-x|<\delta\;\wedge\;|\varphi(t)-\varphi(x)|\geqslant\varepsilon).$$

So, take any $0<\varepsilon\leqslant2$ and let $x\in\mathbb R.$ If $x$ is rational, and if $\delta>0,$ take any irrational $t\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ (whose existence follows from the density of irrationals in $\mathbb R$). Then $|\varphi(t)-\varphi(x)|=2\geqslant\varepsilon.$ A similar process applies if $x$ is rational

Comment: Why do you use that epsilon is less or equal than 2? I mean, why 2?

Comment: @MartinN. $2 = \max |f(x) - f(y)|$. This is used in the second last statement. "Then $|\varphi(t) - \varphi(x)| = 2 \geqslant \varepsilon$."

Comment: @MartinN. Because that's the distance between the two possible distinct values of $\varphi.$ By how it is defined, intuitively, that's what you have to focus on

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJalpaRico Thank you so miuch